# Converting C# DateTime to T-SQL Time in SelectCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, time

I'm trying to return a query (in a gridview in ASP.NET) WHERE Time >= DateTime.Now.Add(-60). The `WHERE` clause has been giving me no end of difficulties.

```
DateTime pastTime = DateTime.Now.Add(-60);    
ds_DB.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [vPurchaseTotals] WHERE [TimeOfTransaction] >=  " + pastTime;
```

My issue is getting pastTime to convert properly, so it only returns the newer data. `[TimeOfTransaction]` is a `time(7)` data type in the table.

How do I parse C#'s `DateTime` to SQL Server's `Time`?

Comment: Use a parameterized query and not string concatenation. That will not only fix your problem but it will prevent against sql injection (when using string types) as well as improve sql servers query cache plan so possible performance boost. See Microsoft article [How to: Execute a Parameterized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: You don't. Pass a parameter instead, of the correct type, so no fiddling with strings is necessary. What is `ds_DB.SelectCommand` -- does it allow parameterization? If not, why not?

Comment: Okay, I will look into parameterization. ds_DB.SelectCommand is a command against the bound datasource of my database.

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    DateTime pastTime = DateTime.Now.Add(-60); 

    ds_DB.SelectCommand = @"SELECT * FROM [vPurchaseTotals]
                            WHERE [TimeOfTransaction] >= @PastTime";

    SqlCommand cm = conn.CreateCommand();
    cm.CommandText = ds_DB.SelectCommand;

    cm.Parameters.Add("@PastTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = pastTime.TimeOfDay; //For comparison with TSQL TIME type

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        // Do what you need to do here.
    }
    catch(SqlException e)
    {
        // Handle Exception
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Just for future reference, you should always parameterize your queries. It ends up being a lot safer and cleaner/easier to read and adjust.

**EDIT:** Are you using a `SqlDataAdapter` class? Is that what ds_DB is an instance of? I would personally just use a string value for your query and then implement the `SqlDataAdapter` like this:

```
try
{
     conn.Open();

     using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm))
     {
          da.Fill(DataTable dt);
     }
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...Also - if the **datatype** in the database is `TIME(7)`, I'd suggest using `SqlDbType.Time` (not `SqlDbType.DateTime`) for your parameter

Comment: So the issue I'm having with understanding parameterization, is that I'm using a datasource that's bound to a gridview control in asp.net. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get an open SQL connection to be bound to a data control.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for those details; that's a helpful bit of information to have; updated to reflect that.